# How can I filter all elements out, which are a substring from another element?

Tags: php, arrays, string, substring

I have an interesting string manipulation issue I'm working through. Suppose I have an array of strings containing both words and substrings of the words:

```
banana
banan
bana
ban
ba
apple
appl
app
ap
```

I want to create a function in PHP which will filter my list down to:

```
apple
banana
```

My first thought is to loop over each array item and check if any substrings of the item exist. If it does, remove that from the array.

Do you have any other suggestions for a solution?

Comment: Loop over the array and if the word/string is not an exact match in your lookup/dictionary (of complete words) then delete it?

Comment: What if substrings are also complete words? Like sand or bag from sandbag?

Comment: Good point. In that case I would need to manually specify which substrings are indeed valid words that shouldn't be deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

Similar to your idea, I just go through each array element with [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and check with [`preg_grep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) if the current array element matches in any other array value. If yes filter it out, else keep it in the array.

```
<?php

    $arr = ["banana", "banan", "bana", "ban", "ba", "apple", "appl", "app", "ap"];
    $newArr = array_filter($arr, function($v)use($arr){
        if(count(preg_grep("/" . preg_quote($v, "/") . "/", $arr)) > 1)
            return FALSE;
        return TRUE;
    });

    print_r($newArr);

?>
```

output:

```
Array ( [0] => banana [5] => apple )
```

<sub>*If you want to reindex your array, just use `array_values()` around the `array_filter()` call.</sub>

Comment: https://3v4l.org/Ll75i less verbose with just one return